# c++ winform error handling

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void link1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
        navigate(url1);
     }


private: System::Void navigate(System::String^ url)
     {
             for each ( System::Windows::Forms::HtmlElement^ webpageelement in webBrowser->Document->All )
             {
                 if (webpageelement->GetAttribute("u"))
                    this->webBrowser->Document->GetElementById("u")->SetAttribute("value", url);
             }

             for each ( System::Windows::Forms::HtmlElement^ webpageelement in webBrowser->Document->All )
             {
                 if (webpageelement->GetAttribute("value") == "Go")
                     webpageelement->InvokeMember("click");
             }
     }
```

i have many other buttons that call the function navigate() but i will only post one coz they are all the same except the value of url. my question is how can i make my application to stop from exiting/have an error if i click the button even if the webpageelement("u") is not present in the form. coz if i click it even if the form is not yet loaded completely i got messagebox said unhandled exception error, i want to change that to something else or just ignore it and let my application try it again. thx

Comment: You will have to fix your code, it cannot work by design.  Move your code to an event handler for the DocumentCompleted event.

Answer (score 1):

Using exception handling for such simple check is an overkill. Simply do following:

```
HtmlElement ele = this->webBrowser->Document->GetElementById("u");
if (ele != null)
  ele->SetAttribute("value", url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `try` and `catch` can give you some basic way... For example

```
for each ( System::Windows::Forms::HtmlElement^ webpageelement in webBrowser->Document->All )
{
    try 
    {
        if (webpageelement->GetAttribute("u"))
        this->webBrowser->Document->GetElementById("u")->SetAttribute("value", url);
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        // Do something here, can be blank...
        // This will try the above code, if it doesn't work it will continue without any error popup
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thx for the answer, but im having error when i try this:

"unable to throw or catch a managed object by value or reference" and

"cannot be caught as the destructor and/or copy constructor are inaccessible"

Comment: You need to put a `^` in the catch clause: `catch (Exception^ ex)`. See edit.